# git equivalent of "hg strip"

Tags: git, mercurial

This question -- or the substantially similar "how to undo `git fetch`" -- has been asked a handful of times before, but the answers have always been too simplistic.  In particular, the most popular answer (`git reset --hard`) doesn't touch the repository at all.

The answer I'm looking for should leave the local git repo (not the working directory, not the index; I don't really care what state those end up in) at the same state (bit-for-bit, ideally) it was in prior to the fetch. I would accept a re-clone of upstream or a modification of the local repo.  I'd be okay with a solution that ignores multiple branches, multiple remotes, etc, but a more full-fledged solution would be nice.

The tests I've been using are:

- `git show` shows `$want`
- `git log` starts at `$want`
- `git show $latest` errors
- `git tag -l $latesttagname` shows nothing
- `git show $latesttag` errors
- `git fetch -v` clearly downloads all the stuff I stripped away (it should *not* say "up to date")

where `$latest` is the commit hash of the head after the fetch I'm trying to undo, `$latesttag` is the commit hash of the newest tagged commit in the set of commits that needs to get stripped, `$latesttagname` is the name of that tag, and `$want` is the commit hash of the old head that I want to be the new head once its descendants are stripped.

The things I tried:

- `git reset --hard $want`: passes only the first two tests
- Adding 'git prune -nv' doesn't help
- Neither does `git gc --prune=now`
- If I clone the repo after doing the `reset`, then in the child the third test passes and the sixth appears (after setting the remote url to the appropriate upstream)
- What makes all the tests pass is to run `git tag -d $(git tag --contains $want | tail +2)` in my local parent before cloning it; in particular, the commits previously referenced by tags are no longer referenced, so I'm guessing they get left behind. But it suggests that there may be other reference types I'm neglecting.
- I brought out the big hammers and did something that kinda seemed to approximate what `hg strip` does (apologies for the zshisms in there):

  ```
  tags=( $(git tag --contains $want | tail +2) )
  mv .git/objects/pack .
  git unpack-objects < pack/pack*.pack
  rm -rf pack
  git log --pretty=format:%H $want..HEAD | while read i; do rm .git/objects/$i[1,2]/$i[3,-1]; done
  git update-ref refs/remotes/origin/master $want
  git update-ref refs/heads/master $want
  for i in refs/tags/$^tags; do git update-ref -d $i; done
  git repack -ad
  ```

  which did pretty much what you'd expect a hammer to do -- break a bunch of things: `git fsck --unreachable` complains about a bunch of invalid reflog entries and unreachable blobs (and one dangling commit), but cloning makes these go away.

It seems to me that the `reset` + tag removal + `clone` is the best of my options here, but a) what other refs do I need to remove/repoint, and b) is there a way to avoid the need for a clone?  Or is there another way entirely?

Apologies for the length of this.  I wanted to be as clear as possible about what I was looking for (and what I wasn't) and what I'd already found to have failed (and why).  If you got this far, thank you.

Comment: `hg strip` (which basically removes commits) and "undo `git fetch`" sound very different things to me. Could you explain more what are you trying to achieve? `git fetch` updates only remote references which do not affect your local branches until you explicitly merge them or use otherwise. So _usually_ there should be no reason to want to undo it.

Comment: I can imagine 2 cases when one might consider `fetch` as harmful and want to undo it: (1) if fetch deletes a remote ref or forcefully updates it, and you lose some valuable commit. But restoring such commit does not sound like what `hg strip` does. (2) when fetch downloads some very big amount of data, which take too much disk space. Undoing this might sound like `hg strip`, but your tests do not mention disk space.

Comment: I'm working on some Makefile magic to perform some automatic actions based on the differences between a build of a git repo at one version and a build of it at a later version.  In order to test my recipes, I want to be able to rewind to precisely the previous state so that I can reproduce an error or confirm that a fixed recipe works as expected. I could do this by saving aside a pristine copy of the older repo and putting it back into place as necessary, but since I neglected to do that originally, and I started down this path, I wanted to see it through to the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TL;DR answer: your reset, remove any tags that point into the reset-away area, and clone method works and is probably the way to go.

If you want to clean out an existing repo, you'll (at least potentially) need `git for-each-ref` and reflog cleaning (of each ref with a reflog, and then also of `HEAD`).

---

It's possible (but noticeably more difficult) to do without cloning, and you're on the right track with `git gc --prune=now` (or `--prune=all` as the documentation says; though it may be better to use an explicit `git repack` and `git prune`, and you probably also need to clear away some reflog entries).

The "big hammer" method may be too aggressive as it can<sup>2</sup> remove objects that are needed as they are the same as objects in commits you're retaining. (Edit after realizing you're just removing commit objects: and, it will probably leave objects behind, although they will not be seen in normal usage. Whether this is a big problem depends on how important it is to remove those objects. See the general theory section below.)

Cloning is easier because a clone brings over only those objects reachable from the references it brings over. That is, you control what gets added, rather than what must be avoided. Your method (remove any leftover tags and make sure no branch contains any of the commits you want gone) will suffice as long as you use a smart protocol and/or expand any packs (see the pack section below).

#### What gets copied

Somewhat formally, suppose the entire repository graph is *`G`* (this is all the objects—commits, tags, trees, and blobs—stored in the repository). A clone finds a subset *`g`* of *`G`* by starting with the branch names being cloned,<sup>1</sup> finding the objects those name, and then recursively adding any objects reachable from those objects. Hence if `refs/heads/master` points to some commit, you get that commit, its tree, any subtrees in its tree, and all blobs associated with those trees; plus the commits that are its parents, their trees, and subtrees and blobs, and so on. Repeat for every name in `refs/heads/` and you have the basic sub-graph *`g`*.

(A `fetch` uses the same process except that the receiver tells the sender which SHA-1 IDs he has as existing branch tips. The sender can use this to exclude objects reachable from those SHA-1s, provided the sender has those SHA-1s. This is only true of the "smart" protocols, but in general you should use smart protocols.)

Both `clone` and `fetch` take a hybrid approach to tags by default. If you add `--tags`, they simply use all the tags presented by the remote in addition to the branch names (incidentally, you can use `git ls-remote` to see all references a remote provides). If you use `--no-tags`, they ignore the tags entirely. Otherwise they ignore the tags initially, build the sub-graph *`g`* as usual, then add as references any tags that point to objects already in *`g`*. For lightweight tags, this adds no objects, but for each annotated tag, this adds the annotated tag object to *`g`* (and if the tag points to something other than a commit, e.g. to another tag — you can get more objects here as well).

Once Git has constructed the clone or fetch graph *`g`*, it extracts the objects, makes a new pack out of them, and sends that pack. This means you don't need to worry about an existing pack containing a "stale" object (which might, for instance, contain sensitive data).

#### Without cloning

If you don't want to clone, though, you must consider all the references Git can see. Both `git gc` and `git prune` (which `git gc` runs for you) will delete unreferenced loose objects. Obviously this means that "being referenced" is one key here. But there's another saving throw, if you will, for loose objects: Git won't delete them if they're very young. (This protects objects being generated before their references get inserted into the repo.) Using `--prune=all` (or `--expire now`) will kill off these objects. Besides these, there's a separate issue with "packed" objects—but let's leave that alone for now.

The other standard references to objects, besides branch, and tag names, are:

- remote-tracking branches (anything in `refs/remotes/`)
- notes (anything in `refs/notes`)
- the stash (`refs/stash`)
- Git's various special-case references: `HEAD`, `FETCH_HEAD`, `ORIG_HEAD`, `MERGE_HEAD`, and `CHERRY_PICK_HEAD` (these are the only normal ones, but any file in `.git` can act as a reference: see [`gitrevisions`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitrevisions.html)

But to be safe you should probably look at `.git/refs` and `.git/packed-refs`, or better, and simpler, use `git for-each-ref`. For each reference discovered, see if it points to a commit you intend to discard; if so, delete (or re-point) that ref. This also covers the case for remote-tracking branch `origin/foo` (which is just `refs/remotes/origin/foo`) when you're deleting or rewinding `foo` on `origin` and don't want those commits showing up.

Next, you'll need to look at the reflogs. If you *delete* a ref, Git (currently) deletes its reflog as well, so this is only for those references that were not deleted in the first pass. A reflog is basically a flat history of each ref. For instance, `refs/remotes/origin/foo` may have named commit `1234567...` before the fetch you're un-doing / stripping, and now names commit `fedcb9a...`. Its reflog will contain `1234567...`. If you want that commit stripped, you need to remove this reflog entry. You can do this with `git reflog delete ref@{number}`; see [the `git reflog` documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-reflog.html). Normally there is a reflog for each branch and each remote-tracking branch, plus one for `HEAD`.

#### Packs

It looks like you already took care of this with `git unpack-objects`, but I'll go over this for completeness.

Even once you have all the references cleaned out, there's still that packed-objects issue: Git may keep unreferenced objects inside packs. To get rid of them you must use `git repack -a -d` to force Git to make a new single pack file and delete any existing pack files. I'm not sure whether this will remove pack files that have an associated `.keep` file (`git gc` won't and `git gc` mostly just runs other commands anyway, so it's possible that `git repack` won't either).

---

<sup>1</sup>And sometimes tags (if you use `--tags`). Normally the branch names selection is "all branch names"—everything in `refs/heads/`—but you can instruct `git clone` to clone only one branch, with `--single-branch`.

<sup>2</sup>The likelihood of this depends on the age of the objects: the oldest objects that get reused wind up in pack files, where they would have been safe if you hadn't unpacked them. :-) Edit: also, I misread the example at first: you're only stripping out *commit* objects, so as long as they're not shared across other branches you should be OK.

Comment: Great detail, thanks.  From the output of `git for-each-ref`, how can I tell whether I should delete or repoint the reference?  Delete if the reference starts with `refs/tags/` and repoint otherwise?  Something like:

Comment: Um, whoops.  Something like

    `... | while read obj ref; do
        if [[ $ref == refs/tags/* ]]; then echo delete $ref $obj;
        elif [[ $obj == $latest ]]; then echo update $ref $want $latest;
        else echo DUNNO: $obj $ref; fi
    done | git update-ref --stdin`

?

Except that when I do that, I get:

    fatal: cannot lock ref 'refs/remotes/origin/HEAD': Unable to create '.../.git/refs/remotes/origin/master.lock': File exists.

The file doesn't exist when I check, but the `git update-ref` is the only git command in the pipeline, so is there some sort of internal race?

Comment: Must be a race, probably want to get all the refs at once and then start updating.  You can supply a format to `git for-each-ref` to control the output.  The documentation even shows how to have it write a script that you then simply pipe to (or save as a file, then run) the shell :)  As for what to do with them, a fancy tool would check whether the tag points to a commit that's being stripped out; it's up to you how fancy you want to get.  Writing a tool in Python or whatever would make it easy to be pretty fancy, for instance.

Comment: The "race" seems to have been an issue with `refs/remotes/origin/HEAD` and `refs/remotes/origin/master` being the same thing; pulling one out of the update-ref instruction stream took care of the error and did what I expected.

Comment: I'm having trouble with the reflog rewrite, though. From `git reflog show`, `HEAD@{1}` and `refs/heads/master@{1}` both have `$latest` in the first column, and I can `git reflog delete` those, but an "empty" entry stays behind with that hash.  And `show refs/remotes/origins/master` has a similar empty entry for it, too.  Plus all the reflog entries refer to it in some way. But if I blow away the `.git/logs` directory entirely, and run `git gc --prune=all` (`git prune --expire=now` doesn't seem to do anything`), then all my tests pass.

Comment: Hm, not sure what's going on with the reflog, but the tools for it are not the best, I think.  Blowing them away entirely is not great but since gc/repack both respect reflogs now, you do have to do *something*.